# How to get some props of list array object by using reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have list array object like:

```
let arr = [
    { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 },
    { a: 2, b: 3, c: 4, d: 5 },
    { a: 5, b: 6, c: 7, d: 8 }
]
```

and after using reduce()

```
// get props **b, c**
let arr_result = arr.reduce( ... )

// arr_result = [
//    { b: 2, c: 3 },
//    { b: 3, c: 4 },
//    { b: 6, c: 7 }
// ]
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `reduce()` when `map()` is much better suit for the job?

Answer (score 2):

use `map`.

```js
let arr = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4
  },
  {
    a: 2,
    b: 3,
    c: 4,
    d: 5
  },
  {
    a: 5,
    b: 6,
    c: 7,
    d: 8
  }
]

const output = arr.map(({b, c}) =>  ({b, c}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ES6(and beyond)'s [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

```js
const arr = [
    { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 },
    { a: 2, b: 3, c: 4, d: 5 },
    { a: 5, b: 6, c: 7, d: 8 }
]

const res = arr.map(obj => {
  const { b, c } = obj;
  return { b, c };
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked to achieve this using reduce, here is the way. Pass an empty array as `thisArg` & inside reduce callback function create an object with required key and push it to the accumulator

```js
let arr = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4
  },
  {
    a: 2,
    b: 3,
    c: 4,
    d: 5
  },
  {
    a: 5,
    b: 6,
    c: 7,
    d: 8
  }
];


let newArr = arr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {

  acc.push({
    b: curr.b,
    c: curr.c
  })

  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `reduce`:

```js
const arr = [{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},{a:2,b:3,c:4,d:5},{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8}];

const res = arr.reduce((a, { b, c }) => (a.push({ b, c }), a), []);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

It's honestly a lot easier with `map`:

```js
const arr = [{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},{a:2,b:3,c:4,d:5},{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8}];

const res = arr.map(({ b, c }) => ({ b, c }));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: const res = arr.reduce((acc, { b, c }) => (acc.push({ b, c }), acc), []);

Can you explain it to me? Tks!

Comment: We're pushing `b` and `c` of each object to a result array `acc`, then returning it for use in the next iteration.